# How to insert two pictures side by side in IEEE access format in two columns paper?

Tags: table-of-contents, sidewaysfigure

How can I insert two pictures in side by side format for the IEEE access format paper? I tried the following code by the pictures are two far away from each other.

```
\begin{figure*}[htp]
  
\centering
 
 \subfigure[random caption 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{image1}}\quad
  
\subfigure[random caption 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{image2}}

\end{figure*}
```

Comment: remove the linebreak between one `\subfigure` and another. Right now you have a quad space then a new line - so LaTeX puts them one under the other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** added are options which preserve original IEEE Access layout for figures and tables.

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{IEEEaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={sf,scriptsize},           % new
            labelfont={bf,color=accessblue},% new
            caption=false]                  % new
           {subfig} 
\begin{document}
\Figure[t!]{example-image-duck}     % for one image per figure
           {Test figure \label{fig:test}} 

\begin{figure*} % for sub figures over two columns in 
\centering
\subfloat[random caption 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}
\hfil
\subfloat[random caption 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}}
\caption{My figure over two column}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure*}
\EOD
\end{document}
```

[image]

- please, always provide complete small document (MWE:  Minimal Working Example), which we can test as it is
- as mentioned in @Elad Den comment, you should remove empty line between images
- don't use obsolete package `subfigure`, instead of it use `subfig` and its environment `\subfloat`
- for image size is better to determine images width than scale it, for example as is done in the above MWE

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly but my figure caption color has been changed. What should I do to keep the figure caption format similar to paper format? Now it's black instead of blue.

Comment: My problem is solved by using following code : \usepackage{caption,setspace} 
\captionsetup{font={sf,small,stretch=0.80},labelfont={bf,color=accessblue}}

Comment: @Taniaislam, see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @zarko

Comment: @Taniaislam, you are welcome!